# (-1)^k for each k from 0 to 9 in R

Tags: r, vector

I'm new to R and I want to create a vector x, length 10 in this case that gives (-1)^k for each k = 0,...,9  in R 
it's supposed to give this [1]  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1
 but it's not working 
I tried this but it doesn't work ..any advice?

```
b<- 0:9
x<- (-1)**b
x
# this should be the answer 
[1]  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1  1 -1
```

Comment: Your code is working fine on my side

Comment: it's not working with me .. I don't know where the problem is :-S

Comment: what is the result you get ? Restart your R session to have a clean session, and retry. Your code is correct.

Comment: You can have the desired result by `rep(c(1, -1), 5)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. And you are right that R will iterate over lists and arrays. If you are having issues getting it to work try expressly creating an array of b

```
b<- c(0,9)
```

This definitely works in all R environments.

Comment: it works now but thnx anyway .. i tried

(b<- seq(0,9))
(y<- (-1)**b)

Comment: hey A_1960 take a look at b itself in that `seq( ) statement to be sure it is what you wanted because `b<- 0:9` returns `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` and `seq(0:9)` returns `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10` ...

Comment: (b<- seq(0,9))
 [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
----
 (b<- c(0:9))
 [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: both are actually giving me this
 [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 .. but here if you type this with colon seq(0:9) instead of this one seq(0,9) with the comma then it's gonna give 
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
--------------------------------
(b<- seq(0,9))
 [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
----
 (b<- c(0:9))
 [1] 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Comment: ok another question please if I wanna take out only the postive entries from x how can I do it ?

Comment: You can just subset: `x[x>0]` which says x where x is greater than zero.